# SwiftUI: Storing an Array in UserDefaults

Tags: swift, swiftui

i am desperate at a point that is probably very easy to solve.
It is no problem for me to store a bool value in UserDefaults. see the attached code.
But I can't manage to change it in a way that I can store multiple toggles with one array.

Anybody got an idea?

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var settings = settingsStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Toggle (isOn: self.$settings.isFavorit) {
                Text("")
                }
        }
        .background(self.$settings.isFavorit.wrappedValue ? Color.green : Color.red)
    }
}


class settingsStore: ObservableObject{
    
    
    @Published var isFavorit: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isFavorit"){
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(self.isFavorit, forKey: "isFavorit")
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Text("Hello, World!")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First don't use UserDefault's `setValue` method. You should use `func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String)`. You can then use UserDefault's method `func array(forKey defaultName: String) -> [Any]?` to get the value and cast it to `[Bool]`

---

```
UserDefaults.standard.set([true, false, true], forKey: "bools")
UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "bools") as? [Bool]  // [true, false, true]
```

---

edit/update:

You can create an isFavorite computed property extending UserDefaults with a getter and a setter to persist your array of booleans. Then you can simply use that value to initialize your published property and update its value when it changes:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    var isFavorite: [Bool] {
        get {
            array(forKey: "isFavorit") as? [Bool] ?? []
        }
        set {
            set(newValue, forKey: "isFavorit")
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class SettingsStore: ObservableObject{
    @Published var isFavorit: [Bool] = UserDefaults.standard.isFavorite {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.isFavorite = self.isFavorit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Leo, many thanks for your answer. I'm very new t swift, so I'm not sure if I understand your answer completely. But I try it to implement it into my code. But maybe I will come back with another question ;-)

Comment: No problem. Be my guest

Comment: ```
 @Published var isFavorit: Array <Bool> = UserDefaults.standard.set([true, false, true], forKey: "bools") ``` is wrong. I read the whole internet ;-), but all I'm trying dosn't work.

Comment: @Michael I've never said for you to do that. I've just showed how to store an array of boolean values and how to retrieve it. I will edit the post to make it clear for you.

Comment: I've solved my problem. @Leo: many thanks! Your solution helped me al lot!